# How can we specify limit to single tags shortcode in buddyboss [bbp-single-tag id=$tag_id]

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, buddyboss

Here I have used boddyboss, now I want show specfic topics but boddyboss provides all topics using  [bbp-single-tag id=80]. I have tried  [bbp-single-tag id="80" posts_per_page="5"] like this shortcode but still not fix. Is there any option to show limited tags?

I have tried [bbp-single-tag id="80" posts_per_page="5"], [bbp-single-tag id="80" post_o=count="5"] but not get expected result